# HttpWebRequest fails after migrating to 2012 R2 to 2019, IIS went from v8 to v10

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I recently had to upgrade to a new server.
2012 R2 to 2019, IIS went from v8 to v10

Everything worked on my old server but on the new one, im having issues.

This same code works on all my sites that use .net framework 4.0 but fail on .net framework 2.0

```
 Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = 
 CType(WebRequest.Create("https://secure.ppsgateway.com/api/transact.php"), HttpWebRequest)
 myRequest.Method = "POST"
 myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 myRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length
 Dim newStream As Stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream()
 newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
 newStream.Close()
```

I tried to isolate where its failing and was able to determine that this particular code is where it fails

```
 Dim newStream As Stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

So im guessing that for some reason, when i upgraded, this code no longer works properly with .net framework 2.0.

I out of ideas :(

Comment: This is the event viewer log error that happens when i try to load the page

Comment: If you don't provide any details (like exact error message, event log entries), expect no answer can be made.

Comment: @DejanandAngelaKnezevic You did not post event viewer log error, please post it.